# How can I compare GBM feature importances to GBM partial dependence plots?

Tags: scikit-learn, boosting, partial-plot

I am having trouble reconciling the difference between the indicated "importance" from a GBM that I am calculating with what is shown in the partial dependence plots.

I would expect higher importance features to have a larger spread on the partial dependence, however it seems that the two are unrelated.  Is this common? Or are these quantities not appropriate to compare (PDP spread and importance)?

Thanks.